# mariadb cannot start with error

Tags: mariadb, collation

i'd rebooted server.

and mariadb did not started automatically.

so i'd type service mysqld start. but shows me cannot start with error.

mariadb cannot start with collation error

i wanna start without error

i'm using centos 6.5

```
**# mysql --version**
mysql  Ver 15.1 Distrib 10.1.19-MariaDB, for Linux (x86_64) using readline 5.1

**# ./mysqld_safe &**
mysqld_safe Logging to '/var/lib/mysql/localhost.localdomain.err'

**localhost.localdomain.err shows me**
mysqld_safe mysqld from pid file /var/lib/mysql/localhost.localdomain.pid ended
mysqld_safe Starting mysqld daemon with databases from /var/lib/mysql
[Warning] '--skip-locking' is deprecated and will be removed in a future release. Please use '--skip-external-locking' instead.
[ERROR] Unknown collation: 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci'
[ERROR] Aborting
[Note] /usr/libexec/mysqld: Shutdown complete

**my.cnf**
[client]
default-character-set=utf8mb4

[mysql]
default-character-set=utf8mb4

[mysqld]
collation-server = utf8mb4_unicode_ci
character-set-server = utf8mb4
```

Comment: Comment out the line with the collation; see if it gets further.  Maybe then further analysis can be made.  (That collation _should_ be available in that version.)

Answer (score 0):

Add

```
skip-character-set-client-handshake
```

under mysqld in my.cnf to resolve any conflicts if collation is set via startup-options.

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/charset-server.html

Comment: it's not sollution.

Answer (score 0):

Whatever server you have on that machine, it is not MariaDB 10.1. `mysql --version` only shows the **client** version, and it is indeed MariaDB 10.1, but the **server** is not.

MariaDB 10.1 wouldn't have thrown a warning upon `skip-locking`, it would have been an error, because this option had been removed long before 10.1. It doesn't even exist in 5.5.

What you most likely have is MySQL 5.1, which is still provided on CentOS 6. Maybe you tried to install MariaDB over it and it didn't go well, or something similar happened.

MySQL 5.1 does not have `utf8mb4`, so the error makes sense, although I would expect it to fail on `character-set-server`. It is possible that you have another config somewhere else which overrides `character-set-server` (and adds `skip-locking` which is not present in your paste, but it must come from somewhere).

Comment: It works well on servers set to the same environment.